# Using switch/enums in SwiftUI Views

Tags: swiftui

As of Xcode 11.4, SwiftUI doesn't allow `switch` statements in Function builder blocks like `VStack {}`, failing with a generic error like `Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred`. How can the `switch` statement be used in SwiftUI to create different Views depending on an enum value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`switch` in SwiftUI view builders is supported since Xcode 12:

```swift
enum Status {
    case loggedIn, loggedOut, expired
}

struct SwiftUISwitchView: View {

    @State var userStatus: Status = .loggedIn

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch self.userStatus {
            case .loggedIn:
                Text("Welcome!")
            case .loggedOut:
                Image(systemName: "person.fill")
            case .expired:
                Text("Session expired")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use enum with `@ViewBuilder` as follow ...

Declare enum

```
enum Destination: CaseIterable, Identifiable {
  case restaurants
  case profile
  
  var id: String { return title }
  
  var title: String {
    switch self {
    case .restaurants: return "Restaurants"
    case .profile: return "Profile"
    }
  }
  
}
```

Now in the View file

```
struct ContentView: View {

   @State private var selectedDestination: Destination? = .restaurants

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
          view(for: selectedDestination)
        }
     }

  @ViewBuilder
  func view(for destination: Destination?) -> some View {
    switch destination {
    case .some(.restaurants):
      CategoriesView()
    case .some(.profile):
      ProfileView()
    default:
      EmptyView()
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to use the same case with the `NavigationLink` ... You can use it as follow

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
  @State private var selectedDestination: Destination? = .restaurants
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {

      List(Destination.allCases,
           selection: $selectedDestination) { item in
        NavigationLink(destination: view(for: selectedDestination),
                       tag: item,
                       selection: $selectedDestination) {
          Text(item.title).tag(item)
        }
      }
        
    }
  }
  
  @ViewBuilder
  func view(for destination: Destination?) -> some View {
    switch destination {
    case .some(.restaurants):
      CategoriesView()
    case .some(.profile):
      ProfileView()
    default:
      EmptyView()
    }
  }
}
```